# PHP search box issuse

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a problem with some php code. So, when I write some text inside search box I should get more results, but I only get 1. This happened to my when I added second query with INNER JOIN. I have no idea why I'm getting only 1 result instead of more, anyone can help?
When I remove second query, it shows me all results.

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM tv_shows WHERE title like :q ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 5');
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$STH->execute(array(
    ':q' => "%$q%"
));

if($STH->rowCount()) {
    while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
        $poster = $row->poster;
        $mtitle = $row->title;
        $mrd = $row->release_date;
        $mid = $row->id;
        $genres = "";

        $STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT g.title from genres g INNER JOIN tv_show_genres tg ON g.id = tg.genre_id INNER JOIN tv_shows t ON t.id = tg.tv_show_id WHERE t.id = :tid');
        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $STH->execute(array(
            ':tid' => $mid
        ));

        if($STH->rowCount()) {
            while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
                $genres .= $row->title.", ";
            }
            echo 
            '<li>
                <span class="search-poster"><img src="'.$poster.'"></span>
                <span class="search-title">'.$mtitle.' ('.$mrd.')</span>
                <span class="search-genre">'.substr($genres,0,-2).'</span>
            </li>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not do another select while the initial select still has unfetched results, or did you?

Comment: You're using the same variable `$STH` for the first statement and the second statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same variable `$STH` for both queries. So when the outer loop gets back to the

```
while ($row = $STH->fetch())
```

line, `$STH` now refers to the second query. Since you've reached the end of the results from that query, calling `fetch()` here returns `false`, so this loop ends as well.

Just use different variable names, e.g. `$show_STH` and `$genre_STH`.

However, an even better solution is to use a single query.

```
SELECT s.poster, s.title AS show_title, s.release_date, g.title AS genre_title
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM tv_shows
      WHERE title like :q 
      ORDER BY title ASC 
      LIMIT 5) AS s
INNER JOIN tv_show_genres tg ON s.id = tg.tv_show_id 
INNER JOIN genres g ON tg.genre_id = g.id
ORDER BY s.title
```

Most of the time when you find yourself performing queries in nested loops like this, you can replace it with a single query that joins the two queries.

Comment: Thanks mate, I just changed variable names and it's working.